# Get entity with filtered inner entities - EF

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have got entity:

```
Entry
{
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the `Entry` that contains filtered `Contents`.

```
var entryWithFilteredContents = dbContext.Entry.Single(). ???
    /*Load(entry=>entry.Contents) Where(content=> content.Value > 10)*/
```

Now when I write `entryWithFilteredContents.Contents` I expect to receive only contents that have Value greater then 10. I know i can get an `var entry = db.Context.Entry.Single()` and then `var contents = entry.Contents.Where(content=> content.Value > 10)` but that don't satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something EF currently supports out of the box.

The usual workaround is to first select a projection, like this:

```
var query = from e in dbContext.Entry
            select new { Entry = e, Related = e.Contents.Where(c => c.Value > 10) };
return query.Where(p => p.Related.Count > 0).Select(p => p.Entry);
```

You can of course also return any projection directly (and potentially save some database round-trips), but will need a non-anonymous type in order to have the result escape the current method.

Comment: Thanks for excellent answer. In that moment I am experimenting with `Join` extension method but with no effects so far.